# Is there a way to exclude pre-order from backorder code in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My client wants to have both pre-orders and backorders in his store. I installed the Woocommerce pre-order plug in which has been working for him.

Now, he wants the Add to Cart button for **backorders** to say "Reserve", so I'm using the code below. However, this changes all the pre-order buttons to "Reserve". Is there something I can add to this code to exclude products are set to pre-order?

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wc_ninja_change_backorder_button', 10, 2 );
function wc_ninja_change_backorder_button( $text, $product ){
    if ( $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $text = __( 'Reserve', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"Is there something I can add to this code to exclude products are set to pre-order"_. Since this will depend on the plugin you are using for this, it might be helpful to mention a link to the plugin, since there are many similar plugins with similar names

Comment: You’re right, thank you. The plug in is https://wordpress.org/plugins/pre-orders-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Question: have you tried your code in combination with [this setting](https://ps.w.org/pre-orders-for-woocommerce/assets/screenshot-3.jpg?rev=2281061)? 
if this doesn't work you can see in the source code from the plugin that based on the following metakey: `_is_pre_order` 
can be checked whether it is true, and if it is, then it is a pre order product. Regards

Comment: @7uc1f3r I know this is months later, but to answer your question, the above code overrides the setting. When I tried using "_is_pre_order", I get a critical error on the website. I asked a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390395/why-is-this-plugin-conditional-tag-breaking-the-website) if you have any ideas. Thank you